# Collapse interesting and ignored tags sections!

Tags: script, tags

Are you annoyed by to large interesting/ignored tags sections?

I've created a user script to collapsing it!

[image]

[Stack Ignore Collapse .user.js](http://hrabstwo.net/hornet/js/stackignorecollapse.user.js)

Comment: +1 Great idea. I have quite a few tags and this script does a good job of hiding them. One small note: I had to modify the script to get it to work on Chrome - I changed all references of `'g()'` to `'document.getElementById()'`.

Comment: Still doesn't know why it didn't work, but I correct script and it works on Chrome:)